# Java MappedByteBuffer.get() surprisingly slow

Tags: java, android, performance, file, mapping

I'm trying to understand if the performance i'm obtaining from the get() method of the MappedByteBuffer class is normal or not. My code is the following:

```jave
private byte[] testBuffer = new byte[4194304];
private File sdcardDir, filepath;
private FileInputStream inputStream; 
private FileChannel fileChannel;
private MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer;

// Obtain the root folder of the external storage
sdcardDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

// Create the reference to the file to be read
filepath = new File(sdcardDir, "largetest.avi");
inputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();

mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, (4194304));

Log.d("GFXUnpack", "Starting to read");
mappedByteBuffer.position(0);
mappedByteBuffer.get(testBuffer, 0, (4194304));
Log.d("GFXUnpack", "Ended to read");
mappedByteBuffer.rewind();
```

Since i'm a beginner, and i needed the fastest way to read data from SD card, i looked for documentation and i found that File Mapping is considered, in many cases, the fastest approach to read from a file. But if i run the above code, although the buffer is correctly filled, the performance is so slow (or maybe not ? You decide !!) that i can read those 4194304 bytes in **almost 5 seconds**, that's **less than 1MB per second**. I'm using Eclipse directly connected to my Optimus Dual smartphone; the same time is required for the read even if i put the reading operation in a loop (maybe overhead initialization wouldn't take place if multiple reads are performed...Not the case).

This file size-time relation doesn't change if i reduce or make the file larger: 8 megs will be read in almost 9 seconds, 2 megs in 2 seconds, and so on.
I've read that even a slow SD card can be read at a speed of at least 5 MB per second...
Note that 4194304 is a power of 2 value, since i've read that this would increase performance.
Please tell me your opinion: is 1MB per second the actual performance on a modern smartphone, or is there something wrong with my code ? Thank you

Comment: Is the performance better if you read with:  while(mappedByteBuffer.hasRemaining())
 {
   mappedByteBuffer.get());
}; ?

Comment: Memory Mapped files make sense if you need random read / write access to files. If you just need to read the data into memory once I'd use the plain old Java io (maybe nio channels). It's also not a great idea to read a 4 or 8MB file into memory on a mobile platform with memory restrictions. Apart from that I tend to say there is something wrong. SD Cards (unless very cheap) should be able to read at least 2MB/s (class 2, still pretty cheap) and phone internal storage should be more like 20MB/s. Try it with a different implementation if you want to be sure that it's not just the hardware limit

Comment: did you try other method to see if you can get better performances ?

Comment: How long does it take to copy this file with native operations (e.g. dragging the folder in Windows)?  This should give you an upper bound on reasonable expectations - if that takes 3+ seconds as well then it would suggest the limiting factor is the SD card or the (US)Bus.

Comment: @GunnarKarlsson : sadly no, i get exactly the same performance

Comment: @zapl : thanks for the tip, this was actually just a test. In the actual code i will use 512KB buffers or so. Note: i've just tried plain nio channels, and i got a performance increase (??), now i can read almost 2 megabytes in a second. Not perfect, but better indeed !!

Comment: @njzk2 : for now, i've just tried nio channels. I made a separate dummy app to test file reading strategies, and i will try other approaches

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle : i did that test and was no lucky, copying from/to PC (connected to smartphone via USB) was almost instantly done with the very same 4 megs file used for the test. So, it's not an hardware issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your code.  It is probably just the speed of the device and / or the file system implementation.  As [Tom Hawtin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/537516/139985) puts it "[m]emory mapped I/O will not make your disks run faster".

Comment: After all, we're talking about a very minimal amount of instructions, i think it couldn't be more optimised. I tried to pull those instructions out of the original project - which included multithreading and locks/unlocks - and i put them in a almost empty project, but i got the same reading times

Answer (score 3):

Its worth nothing that in the Hotspot JVM,  MappedByteBuffer.get() uses an intrinsic rather than a native call.  When copying large sections blocks of data it copies multiple bytes at a time e.g. 8 bytes or longer with MMX instructions.

AFAIK, Android doesn't do this, which makes this call much more expensive.

Comment: While I don't doubt that what you say is true, this doesn't explain why the read rate is as low as the OP observes.  At the very least, it cannot be the whole answer.

Comment: To test the performance of the hardware you could try copying the file on the phone or to/from a PC (not in Java)