# What is the most efficient way to read a big text file backwards?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, optimization

What is the **most efficient** way to read a **big** text file backwards, line by line, using **Windows API** functions? For example, if a file is:

```
line 1
...
line 108777
line 108778
```

the output should be:

```
line 108778
line 108777
...
line 1
```

I want to write a C program for this. You don't need to write a code (but if you want, that's great), I am just interested in how to do this having in mind that files are big and that I want program to run as fast as it can.

Also, I am interested in which Windows API functions to use.

Comment: Without forward indexing the file, I think this would be tricky in the case of multibyte encodings.

Comment: I don't think there are any multibyte encodings where '\n' can appear as part of another character, so synchronization on '\n' should be fine. Of course I wouldn't bother to support any of the insane multibyte encodings whether one character can be a substring of another character, only UTF8.

Comment: Is there a reason for using *Windows API* rather than the facilities of the language?  This can be performed without using *Windows API* functions.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I must do this using windows API... Sad, but true

Answer (score 3):

A more clever solution is to open the file, set the file-offset to the (end of the file - buffersize) and read (buffersize) bytes, u can parse the data in the buffer from back to front to find newlines and do whatever you want, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is more important than memory utilization, I'd just do a buffered read of the entire text file into memory and then parse it in whatever order you like.

Take a look at [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx), some advantages of which are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192527/what-are-the-advantages-of-memory-mapped-files).

Answer (score 2):

[Memory-map the file.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) It will be automatically buffered for you - just read it as if it was memory, starting from the tail and looking for CRs / LFs / CRLFs.

Answer (score 2):

Memory mapped files will fail (or at least become very tricky) if the file's bigger than the available address space. Instead, try this:

```
input = input file
block_prefix = unique temporary file
block_index = 0

while (!eof (input))
{
   line = input.readline ();
   push line onto a stack

   if (stack > 100 entries) // doesn't have to be 100
   {
      output = block_prefix + block_index++

      while (stack has entries)
      {
        pop line off stack
        write to output
      }
   }
}

if (stack has entries)
{
  output = block_prefix + block_index++

  while (stack has entries)
  {
    pop line off stack
    write to output
  }
}

output = output file

while (block_index)
{
   read entire contents of block file (block_prefix + --block_index)
   write contents to output
   delete block file
}
```

Comment: so you are copying the whole file to a temp file just so that you can read the temp file again?

Answer (score 2):

One method is to use a container of file offsets to the beginning of each line.  After parsing the file, process the container in reverse order.  See `fgetc`, `fgets` and `fseek`.

Comment: +1.  Scan the file once and put each end-of-line position on a stack.  Then get into a loop of popping of file position pointers off the stack and seek to that position.  Print all the characters between that stack value and the previous one.