# Bit Shift Large Binary File?

Tags: c, binary, bit, bit-shift

What is the best or recommended method for bit shifting a large amount of binary data in C? I have a 200K binary file and I want to left, then right shift the entire lot.

Comment: How far left & right are you wanting to shift it ? and are you wanting to preserve data or are you willing to lose it (and keep the same size file) ?

Comment: What's "shifting a file" supposed to do? From your description it sounds that you only need to shift a little inside some kind of loop. Please provide more details.

Comment: Want to preserve the data on the shift back.  Should be identical as before I performed the shifting.

Comment: I think @Jon is right, just loop through your file & create a new one in the process. Dont forget to check for loss of data at word boundaries. (or however large a data item you can shift on!)

Comment: @Jon: It's a study in shifting a very large number.  Looking for the best or known techniques.  Thought about putting the data into a char* then looping across that while performing bitwise, but I suspect I need to convert those "string" characters into their decimal equivalent then perform the operations one number at a time.

Comment: Joe: Well, right now a binary (or decimal) number that is 200k long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your OS can support it use a memory mapped file. Then do a bit shift It'll be very very efficient.

See this answer for more info: [What are the advantages of memory-mapped files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192527/what-are-the-advantages-of-memory-mapped-files)

Comment: Ok, I'll Google "memory mapped file".  Appreciate.